# how to restore anaconda environment if google cloud disconnected

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, anaconda

I was training neural network program before disconnected with my instance. The training was running the second epoch with some result:

[image]

I have created anaconda environment with python2. 
When I connected again, re-enter the anaconda environment, I can't see anything.Do I have chance to find the result?

Comment: What's available depends on your libs/code (e.g. snapshots to hdf5 or co). But in general: losing the connection means the process is stopped. Usually people use tmux or something similar to be able to re-attach after logging out.

Answer (score 1):

If you had SSH'd into the instance, loosing the connection would result in your process being aborted, unfortunately.

In the future, you can use a terminal multiplexer like [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) or [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) to keep the terminal window open for an extended period of time.

Comment: what about using docker? maybe I can reconnect using docker attach?